# Standard SAP S/4HANA API to query ArchiveLink tables and get metadata

Tags: sap-basis, dms, s4hana

The setup is:

- on-prem S/4HANA
- third-party document management system (DMS) using ArchiveLink to store all types of documents

By design, ArchiveLink is used only to store the files in the external DMS and store links between files and business objects in the tables TOA01, TOA02 and TOA03.

However, in my DMS, I would like to have some metadata like author, title, document type... for each stored file.

In order to get those information, I need that the DMS queries S/4HANA with the GUID of a stored document as input paramter.

My question : is it possible to use only standard API available on api.sap.com to implement that integration?